# Django 1.5 view with related formset (master detail view)

Tags: django

I would like to be able to have a view displaying the master model and then, within that view display detail forms. (E.g. Order with Orderlines).

I am having trouble in finding a way to do this, I would like to use Class based views.

The master model data within the view does not need to be edited within this view, but the detail records should be able to be edited and added too.

Any best practices for achieving this master detail view.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to hook in to the `get_context_data` method of the `View`.

```
class DetailedView(DetailView):
    model = Model

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DetailedView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'randomList': ['badgers', 'lightbulbs', 42]
        })
        return context
```

`randomList` will now be available in your template.  Obviously this is fairly simple but you can pull in any data, forms etc that you want.